# Should I use wait() to wait for dialog to close? Is there a better way?

Tags: cypress

I want to test that when I click a button that closes a modal dialog (ng material) that the modal does not exist.

**This test actually closes the modal but it passes**

```
it('should close the modal when the close button is clicked', () => {
            cy.get('#close-new-category').click();
            cy.get('#new-category').should('exist');
});
```

**This test works also**

```
it('should close the modal when the close button is clicked', () => {
            cy.get('#close-new-category').click();
            cy.get('#new-category').should('not.exist');
});
```

**This test fails, if I add a wait**

```
it('should close the modal when the close button is clicked', () => {
                cy.get('#close-new-category').click();
                cy.wait(500);
                cy.get('#new-category').should('exist');
});
```

**This test passes as we should expect, but is using wait() the best way?**

```
it('should close the modal when the close button is clicked', () => {
            cy.get('#close-new-category').click();
            cy.wait(500);
            cy.get('#new-category').should('not.exist');
});
```

I only ask because the documentation says this is an anti-pattern and there should be a better way.

Comment: I do believe in this scenario it is valid to use a `cy.wait()` to be more explicit about the timing intentions of the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not need to use wait() for the purpose of these tests. I think these examples are testing too much like unit tests and not enough like end to end tests.

The reason case #1 passes is that after clicking close the modal still does exist for some small amount of time. The should() checks immediately in this case and still sees your modal, so it passes and moves on.

Case #2 also passes because should() has built in retry logic, this is one of the key features of cypress. Immediately after clicking close, the should() checks and finds that the modal does exist. Because the modal is found, it will wait and try again. Eventually the modal does go away and this should() passes.

For the purposes of your testing scenario, you only need to care about case #2 because it tests that your modal does go away. After that should() passes, you are able to move forward to the next step of your test knowing that the modal is gone. The fact that it was still there initially doesn't matter to what you want to accomplish next.